# I need to split a very large text file

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a large text file(more than my RAM) and I need to use each line in it for further processing​. But if I read say like 4096 bytes at a time I'm worried about splitting the line somewhere in between. How do i proceed?

Comment: You could read a character at a time until you stumble upon a new line character (`\n` or `\r\n`) and then write the data before the new line into another file.

Comment: Wouldn't it make the processing a lot slower?

Comment: or read data in chunks and scan those for new lines and then see if the chunk doesn't end with a new line. If it doesn't and there's more data to read from the file, do so and concatenate the new chunk with the rest of the previous one. Then repeat the process.

Comment: Are some lines exceed the size of the memory you can spend on this task?

Comment: If it's a text file, read it a line at a time, adding each line to a list. You can keep track of how many characters have been read by adding the length of each one to an accumulator, but check beforehand to see if it's time to process a "chunk".

Comment: I cannot actually tell if a line exceeds the memory... I guess ForceBru's approach makes sense

Comment: Thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```
SIZE = 1024

with open('file.txt') as f:
    old, data = '', f.read(SIZE)

    while data:
          # (1)
        lines = data.splitlines()
        if not data.endswith('\n'):
            old = lines[-1]
        else:
            old = ''

        # process stuff

        data = old + f.read(SIZE)
```

1. If you do `data.splitlines(True)`, then new line characters will be kept in the resulted list.

Answer (score 2):

Read the file using a generator:

```
def read_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as lines:
        for line in lines:
            yield line
```

That way you never have more than one line in memory at a time, but will still read the file in order.

Comment: I am concerned if even one line  can exceed my memory...I cannot even open the file normally to check...

Comment: Thanks though...This is a nice solution if I'm sure that a line is of fixed length...

Comment: yield does not add any value here... {{for line in lines}}, calls a file iterator..which already loads data line by line in a memory...you could just do: {{for line in lines: doSomethingWithThisLine()}} function and be good with it

Answer (score 1):

One does this sort of thing in audio coding lots, where files can be huge. The normal way as I understand it is just to have a memory buffer and do it in two stages: read a blob of arbitrary size into buffer (4096 or whatever), then stream characters from the buffer, reacting to the line endings. Because the buffer is in ram, streaming character by character out of it is fast. I'm not sure what data structure or call would be best to do it with in Python though, I've actually only done this in C, where it's just a block of ram. But the same approach should work.

Comment: Thanks...I'm just a beginner, I'm dealing with data of such volume for the first time...

Answer (score 1):

On linux:

put this into a python script, for example, *process.py*:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    #do something with the line, for example:
    output = line[:5] + line[10:15]
    sys.stdout.write("{}\n".format(output))
```

to run the script, use:

```
cat input_data | python process.py > output
```